# Spark Scala - Save data frame as text files with headers

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`DataFrameWriter` `csv` method generates csv part files with headers

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("header","true").option("delimiter", "\t")
.csv("/tmp/files")
```

Databrick's spark-csv as well does the csv file with headers, but has nothing for text files with headers.

```
dataFrame.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter",<your delimiter>)
  .save(output)
```

However, the text method generates text files with data only and no headers(column names)

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header","true")
.option("delimiter", "\t")
.text("/tmp/files")
```

I have tried using `saveAsTextFile` on `RDD` but the result is same i.e. text files with no headers.

```
df.rdd.map(c => c(1) + "\t" + c(0) + "\t" + c(2))
.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/files")
```

How can I get part text files with headers ?

Comment: as you mention yourself the CSV works - why do you want to use the text format?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `text` method. If you want header and delimiters you should use `csv` method:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .csv("/tmp/files")
```

Comment: Understand! But i have a limitation to use .txt files ONLY and that too with headers.

Comment: I didn't find a way to convert my data frame to text files with headers. Hence i'm doing a two step process, where i first convert my data frame to csv files to a temp location and then stream the files and use saveAsTextFile to convert them to text files with headers.

Comment: @Vicky can you please let me know how you have written text files with headers , I am facing issue with header is not at top